# Scala: getting the key (and value) of a Map.head element

Tags: scala, collections, dictionary

Let's imagine the following immutable Map:

```
val foo = Map((10,"ten"), (100,"one hundred"))
```

I want to get the key of the first element.

`foo.head` gets the first element. But what next?

I also want the value of this element, i.e. "ten"

Comment: `Map`s aren't sorted. So 'first' isn't always what you think it is. Just keep that in mind :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Set a key/value pair:
`val (key, value) = foo.head`

Comment: Is there a way to get the top 2 (key, value) pairs or top 3 instead of only the first.

Answer (score 23):

Map.head returns a tuple, so you can use _1 and _2 to get its index and value.

```
scala> val foo = Map((10,"ten"), (100,"one hundred"))
foo: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map(10 -> ten, 100 -
> one hundred)

scala> val hd=foo.head
hd: (Int, java.lang.String) = (10,ten)

scala> hd._1
res0: Int = 10

scala> hd._2
res1: java.lang.String = ten
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. IODEV's solution looks very nice I must say.

Answer (score 1):

I must say that @Paolo Falabella had the best answer, as using

```
val (key, value) = foo.head
```

in a tail-recursive method will lead to a crash!

So it is much better/more versatile to use

```
val myMap = Map("Hello" ->"world", "Hi" -> "Everybody")
print(myMap.head._1)
```

which would print "Hello" and won't cause a crash in a tails recursive method.