# What data type do I get when I iterate over a map?

Tags: scala

I have an application which has to gather some external data first, then turn them into objects. Afterwards, it will do some analysis on the data.

I managed to gather the data and put it into a map. The map contains a unique key for each of the future objects, and a ListBuffer of the data needed to build the object.

Now I want to create a list of objects from this map, and don't know how to get my data out of the map. I haven't worked with maps before (yes, I am that new to the language), but found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778405/scala-getting-the-key-and-value-of-a-map-head-element) which says that, when I want to access an element of the map with `head`, I get a tuple of the key and the value. I hoped that I get the same when I iterate over the map with `map` (the method), but this doesn't appear to work. And I looked in Programming with Scala, but couldn't find a place saying what I get when I iterate over a map.

Here is an MWE for what I want to do:

```
//This code will gather number names from different languages and then create objects of type Number containing each name. 


import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer


class Number (val theNumber: Int, val names: List[String]) {
  override def toString = theNumber + " is known as " + names.mkString(", ") + "."
}

// Construct a map holding example data 
val numbersAsMap = mutable.Map.empty[Int, ListBuffer[String]] 

numbersAsMap += (1 -> new ListBuffer[String])
 numbersAsMap += (2 -> new ListBuffer[String])
numbersAsMap += (3 -> new ListBuffer[String])

numbersAsMap(1) += "one"
numbersAsMap(1) += "eins"
numbersAsMap(1) += "uno"

numbersAsMap(2) += "two"
numbersAsMap(2) += "zwei"
numbersAsMap(2) += "due"

numbersAsMap(3) += "three"
numbersAsMap(3) += "drei"
numbersAsMap(3) += "tre"

// Create a list of numbers 
numbersAsMap map ((key, value) => new Number(key, value.toList)).toList
// error: missing parameter type

// obviously I'm not getting tuples, let's try it another way
numbersAsMap.keys map (key => new Number(key, numbersAsMap(key).toList)).toList
// it throws the same error as above :(
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `map` method of `Map` complies with the `map` method of other collections, so it's body only gets one parameter. In case of a `Map`, this is a tuple consisting of the key and the value.

So you can write:

```
numbersAsMap.map(kv => new Number(kv._1, kv._2.toList)).toList
```

If you want to name the tuple values:

```
numbersAsMap.map {
  kv =>
    val (key, value) = kv
    new Number(key, value.toList)
}.toList
```

But there is another option to write it nicely in a single line: Use a partial function:

```
numbersAsMap.map { case (key, value) => new Number(key, value.toList) }.toList
```

A `{ case ... }` defines a partial function; and this way you can extract the values of the tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possible ways to do the `map` operation on your `Map`:

```
val result = numbersAsMap.map{
  case (key, value) =>
    new Number(key, value.toList)
}.toList

val result2 = numbersAsMap.map(kv => new Number(kv._1, kv._2.toList)).toList
```